# Доступ к request.user в admin.py для условие к readonly_fields

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-admin

Использую стандартный Django-Admin версия 2*. 
Есть класс Кард с полем number.

```
class Card(models.Model):
     number = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True, default="")
```

Нужно получить доступ в `admin.py`/`Card_Admin` , к группам пользователей  "A" и "B". Что бы написать условие где группа А может только просмотреть field а группа Б может редактировать.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group


class Card_Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     if Group.objects.get(name='A').user_set.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
         readonly_fields = ['number']
```

Так же проблема с  запросом который после перехода на вторую версию перестал работать. В версии 1.11 запрос работал во views.py, а в админ-классе так же не мог получить доступ к `request.user`.

```
Group.objects.get(name='A').user_set.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Card_Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        if request.user.groups.filter(name='A').exists():
            return ['number']
        return []
```